# PHP preg_replace modification

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have an expression `[text][id]` which should be replaced with a link `<a href='id'>text</a>`

The solution is (`id` is integer)

```
$s = preg_replace("/\[([^\]]+)(\]*)\]\[([0-9]+)\]/","<a href='$3'>$1$2</a>",$string);
```

However, in some cases (not always!) the expression may be as the following

```
[text][id][type]
```

which should in this case be replaced with `<a href='id' class='type'>text</a>`

Ideas?

Comment: There are no numbers in your example what is `\[([0-9]+)\]` doing? or `id` is an integer?

Comment: Yes, ID is integer

Comment: What are `text` and `type`? I think you are going to need 2 regex for this because the replacement is going to need have `class="$3"` everytime, or I guess you could strip it in another step, if empty.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/PKydSV

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution using [***preg_replace_callback***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function:

```
$str = 'some text [hello][1] some text [there][2][news]';  // exemplary string

$result = preg_replace_callback('/\[([^][]+)\]\[([^][]+)\](?:\[([^][]+)\])?/',function($m){
    $cls = (isset($m[3]))? " class='{$m[3]}'" : "";  // considering `class` attribute
    return "<a href='{$m[2]}'$cls>{$m[1]}</a>";
},$str);

print_r($result);
```

The output (as web page source code):

```
some text <a href='1'>hello</a> some text <a href='2' class='news'>there</a>
```

---

- `(?:\[([^][]+)\])?` - considering optional 3rd captured group (for *class* attribute value)